# Assistance requested for help in restructuring my PHP class methods

Tags: php

Hopefully somebody can help with this problem

My objective: to create a class that creates HTML forms.

```
$cont->individual_fields("text", "feedName", "feed-name", null, "The name of the feed:", "200", "YES");
```

The above uses the individual_fields() method to add values for the various HTML attributes to be found in a text input field.

The method:

```
public function individual_fields($type, $name, $id, $class = null, $desc, $maxlength = null, $value = null, $select = null) { }
```

Within the method I create a multidimensional array:

```
    $fields_essentials = array(
        'type' => $type,
        'name' => $name,
        'id' => $id,
        'desc' => $desc,
        'class' => $class,
        'maxlength' => $maxlength,
        'value' => $value,
        'select' => $select);
```

So I now have a multidimensional array with attribute labels and values. Great.

Now I use a foreach to loop through array creating the HTML form field.

So it ends up with:

```
$text = '<tr>';
$text .= "<th><label for=\"$id\">$desc</label></th>";
$text .= '<td><'.$form.' ></td>';
$text .= '</tr>';

return $text;
```

The HTML is as follows:

```
<label for="feed-name">The name of the feed:</label>

<input type="text" value="" maxlength="200" class="regular-text code " id="feed-name"name="affiliate_hoover_plugin_options[feedName]"/>
```

All super smashing so far.

Now the problem I have is taking the returned results of the individual_fields() method and placing it into another method called create_form():

```
echo $cont->create_form("post", "#action", "optionForm", "option-form", "multipart/form-data");

public function create_form($method, $action = null, $name = null, $id = null, $enctype = null) {

    extract($this->config_settings());

    $form = null;

    $form .= "<form method=\"$method\" ";

    ($action !== null) ? $form .= " action=\"$action\"" : null;
    ($name !== null) ? $form .= " name=\"$name\"" : null;
    ($id !== null) ? $form .= " id=\"$id\"" : null;
    ($enctype !== null) ? $form .= " enctype=\"$enctype\"" : null;

    $form .= ">";
    $form .= '<fieldset>';
    $form .= "<legend>$page_title</legend>";

    $form .= '<table class="form-table">';
    $form .= '<tbody>';

    $form .= '</tbody>';
    $form .= '</table>';
    // input fields here

    // INDIVIDUAL FIELDS FROM individual_fields() method here

    // permenant settings for every form
    $form .= $this->perm_fields();
    $form .= '<input type="submit" id="submit" name="submitForm" class="button-primary" value="Save Changes">';
    $form .= '</fieldset>';
    $form .= '</form>';

    return $form;

}
```

**How do I save the returned values from the individual_fields() method and use it in the create_form() method?**

I've tried so many different approaches and spent a hell of a lot of time on this issue that I wonder if the problem lies in how I am structuring my class methods rather than an issue of scope.

If you have read this post from top to bottom, I thank you

Edit:

Reading the responses below and thinking about it a bit more I may just add the field details as any array to the create_form function so it looks like this:

```
$cont->create_form("post", "#action", "optionForm", "option-form", "multipart/form-data", array("text", "feedName", "feed-name", null, "The name of the feed:", "200", "YES"), array("text", "urlName", "url-name", null, "The URL of the feed:", "300", "YES"));
```

It's a bit more of a complex lump of code that I wanted though. It would have been nice to be able to separate it.

Comment: Your question might be more appropriate at: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Why can't you use `$form .= $this->individual_fields();` ?

Comment: @galymzhan yes I can if I include the parameters but I wanted to organise my code so that it is separate. I suppose one way of doing it is to add an array parameter to the create_field() method and then use the info in that for the individual_fields() method. A bit messy though as I wanted to make sure using the code would be more simple than that.

Answer (score 1):

You may create function (in `$cont`) like this:

```
protected $fields = array();

function push_field( $field){
    $this->fields[] = $field;
}

// And usage:
$cont->push_field( $text);

// In create form:
foreach( $this->fields as $field){
    echo $field . "\n";
}
```

However I'd create class like this:

```
class Field {
  $attrbites = array(); // HTML attributes
  $properties = array(); // Like field title or so

  public function __construct($type, $name, $id, $class = null, $desc, $maxlength = null, $value = null, $select = null) { }

  public function getHtml(){ ...
    return $text;
  }
}
```

And generate all html just when displaying form, than you could add *validation* to `Field`, add *Decorators* and manipulation with them would be easier.